# JavaScript Get Texts

Tags: javascript

I have a strange required, where I have to take multiline text as an INPUT and corresponding output as shown below using JavaScript.

INPUT

2020-11-30 15:21:00 - xxx (Comments)
Request for Signature - yyyy for xxx is approved

2020-11-30 15:21:00 - xxx (Comments)
This is a comment of xxx as the final approver of the legal team.

2020-11-30 14:15:56 - rrr (Comments)
reply from: miyuki.kondo@airliquide.com

rrr の Request for Signature - General Contracts を承認します

2020-11-30 14:15:56 - rrr (Comments)
契約書捺印依頼(一般) for rrr is approved

2020-11-30 14:12:26 - xxx (Comments)
This is a comment of xxx as the 1st approver.

2020-11-30 14:12:26 - xxx (Comments)
Request for Signature - yyyy for xxx is approved

OUTPUT

xxx (Comments)
Request for Signature - yyyy for xxx is approved

xxx (Comments)
This is a comment of xxx as the final approver of the legal team.

rrr (Comments)
reply from: miyuki.kondo@airliquide.com

rrr の Request for Signature - General Contracts を承認します

rrr (Comments)
契約書捺印依頼(一般) for rrr is approved

xxx (Comments)
This is a comment of xxx as the 1st approver.

xxx (Comments)
Request for Signature - yyyy for xxx is approved

Comment: So basically you want to strip the date at the start of your strings?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let str = "2020-11-30 15:21:00 - xxx (Comments) Request for Signature - yyyy for xxx is approved";
let split = str.split(' - ').slice(1).join(' - ');
console.log(split);
```